# Debian booting to black screen

Tags: debian, fstab

I just finished upgrading to Jessie from Wheezy, and after a reboot, my system ran grub, goes through some checks and stuff after loading the kernel. It then says:

```
Welcome Debian 8 servername Tty1 Login:
```

But the screen goes black before I can do anything. I can enter recovery mode, and have been trying some things.

1. I ran `apt-get update` and `upgrade` and it shows no new downloads
2. I have tried running grub with `nomodeset`
3. Drivers installed on my GPU are `gflrx`

In `journalctl -xb` I see this error:

```
Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/plymouth
```

[This guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170667/failed-at-step-exec-spawning-bin-plymouth-debian-testing?newreg=5851732c321f42ce87b195287b0ec507) says to modify my `fstab` file, but I only have three devices in there: `/`, `usr`, and `swap`. None of those correspond to a CD drive.

I can also run as sysvinit which looks like it's running fine, then gets to apache2 and the screen goes black.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have Plymouth installed? https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a solution, but temporary workaround which enabled me to reach the login screen:

- in GRUB, open command line and check which modules are loaded with `lsmod`
- load the normal module (strangely enough, for me it worked after i had tried to load with both `insmod (hd0,5)/boot/grub/normal.mod` and `insmod normal`)
- return to normal grub module with `normal` and select the OS you wish to load
- overwrite GRUB settings

Haven't managed to locate the root cause of this issue though but it vaguely hints that something messes up GRUB.